# Soy nuevo, Se pueden crear migraciones teniendo laravel en Hosting con Cpanel?

Tags: laravel, artisan

Soy nuevo en Laravel, estoy trabajando directamente en Cpanel en un servicio Hosting, hasta donde he visto artisan se encarga también de las migraciones a través de la terminal en local, pero ¿Cómo puedo crear mis migraciones en mi condición de estar trabajando ya en línea?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso por SSH? Es la forma habitual para ejecutar comandos por consola en remoto.
En este articulo hay varias alternativas: https://living-sun.com/es/php/663725-how-to-execute-ldquophp-artisan-migraterdquo-and-other-laravel-commands-in-remote-server-php-laravel-frameworks-remote-server.html

Comment: Tu Cpanel tiene una terminal y composer instalado, puede entrar a la carpeta del proyecto y ejecutar las migraciones